# Simple NMOS transistor circuit output impedance

Tags: transistors, impedance, thevenin, nmos

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to determine the output impedance of this simple NMOS transistor circuit:

[image: NMOS transistor circuit]

Both transistors are equal, and the body effect is ignored.

What method should I use to find the output impedance? Should I find the transistors' small-signal equivalent and then use Thevenin and simply add resistances of both transistors together, or is there another method I could use?

Also, won't the output impedance vary with the drain current? Will it then be a function of \$V_{\text{ref}}\$?

EDIT:

I have tried to reduce the circuit down to its small signal equivalent using the t-model for an active NMOS. Is this correct?

[image]

EDIT 2:

Can the small signal equivalent circuit be reduced using Thevenin into something like this?

[image]

I feel like I am missing something here. It just seems too easy to be true.

Comment: Use the small signal equivalent, apply a test voltage to the drain of \$Q_1\$, and measure the current from that test voltage (or, equivalently, apply a test current and measure its voltage).

Comment: Output impedance is a small signal effect so yes, you will need to use the ss-equivalent. The ss-equivalent circuit will not change but the values of the components will change depending on large-signal parameters. So yes drain current and Vref will have an impact. But first make the ss-equivalent and then see what changes when Ids changes etc.

Comment: @Null: I have attempted to find the ss-equivalent of the circuit. Is this correct?

Comment: It looks largely correct. The only thing I see wrong is that \$V_{\text{ref}}\$ is a DC bias voltage, so it is a small signal ground. +1 for the effort, by the way.

Comment: @Null: Cheers. I have made an attempt to use Thevenin to find the output resistance, but I might be missing something...

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you can combine the resistors that way, but the last drawing looks like it will give you an incorrect result. I think you should get a term with \$r_{ds1} \times r_{ds2}\$. This circuit is similar to the [Wilson current mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_current_mirror#MOSFET_Implementation), which has such a term. I haven't had time to work out the problem, but the issue with your last diagram may be that there is no current flowing to the \$V_{\text{ref}}\$ small signal ground and perhaps you can't put \$r_{s1}\$ in parallel with the other two for that reason.

Comment: I usually use the hybrid-\$\pi\$ small signal model. That might be an easier model in this case. (Again, I haven't had time to work out the problem myself, so I'm not sure.)

Comment: Then again, the Wilson current mirror may not apply. The multiplied resistances include a MOSFET that is not used in your circuit. So you may be on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

So I spent some time researching the problem, and I came up with a possible solution:

First we draw the small signal equivalent for the circuit and add a test voltage \$v_{\text{d}}\$:

[image]

I have made the assumption that \$r_{\text{ds1}}\$ = \$r_{\text{ds1}}\$ = \$r_{\text{ds}}\$ because the transistors are identical.

We find expressions for \$i_{\text{d}}\$ in the top part:

[image]

And for \$i_{\text{d}}\$ in the lower part:

[image]

We seperate out \$v_{\text{s}}\$

[image]

And insert it into the first expression for \$i_{\text{d}}\$:

[image]

We then solve for \$R_{\text{s}}\$:

[image]

Which is the output impedance.

If anyone could verify if the answer above is correct or incorrect, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @OKHS seems to be correct with the given assumptions. Just for the sake of completeness, please note that when there is a resistance \$\mathrm{R_s}\$ seen at the course of an NMOS transistor, the output impedance is (at low frequencies)

\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm{R_{out}=R_s+r_{ds}+g_m r_{ds} R_s} 
\end{equation}

The derivation is really a simple exercise of KVL-KCL. Now the impedance of a diode-connected NMOS Q2 is just \$\mathrm{R_s = \frac{1}{g_{m2}} \parallel \frac{1}{r_{ds2}}} \$ (another simple exercise). So the total impedance seen looking into the drain of Q1 can be easily calculated.

Now, **for all practical purposes and if the transistors are sized and biased correctly**, the output impedance equation can be simplified to
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm{R_{out} \approx r_{ds}+g_m r_{ds} R_s = r_{ds}\left(1 + g_m R_s\right)} 
\end{equation}

and also when \$\mathrm{1/g_m}\$ is parallel with \$\mathrm{r_{ds}}\$, we often just consider \$\mathrm{1/g_m}\$.

So the output impedance for your example can be approximated by
\begin{equation} 
  \mathrm{R_{out}=r_{ds1}\left(1 + \frac{g_{m1}}{g_{m2}}\right)} 
\end{equation}
which is \$\mathrm{2r_{ds1}}\$ if \$\mathrm{g_{m1}=g_{m2}}\$

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBt68A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Vtest and Itest is related as:

***Vtest = (Itest + gm1.Vx).rds1 + (Itest - gm2.Vx).rds2***

Assuming transistors are identical, gm1 = gm2, rds1 = rds2

We get Rout = Vtest/Itest = 2.rds